# Abrir janela 1 unica vez

Tags: javascript, html

Estou querendo que ao clicar na pagina uma janela abre e estou usando esse código

```
 <script>
document.onclick = function( e ){
 myFunction();
}

function myFunction() {
window.open("http://google.com.br", "_blank", "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=1, left=1, width=1, height=1");
}
</script>
```

Mas ele abre toda Vez que e clicado na janela queria que ele fosse executado uma unica vez e depois so volta-se a ser executado se a janela fosse recarregada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque um variável de controle com o nome de `status`, ***exemplo***:

```
<script>

    var status = 0;
    document.onclick = function( e )
    {
        myFunction();        
    }

    function myFunction() 
    {
        if (status == 0) 
        {
            window.open("http://google.com.br", "_blank", 
       "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=1, left=1, width=1, height=1");
        }
        status = 1;
    }

</script>
```

ou até no `documento.onClick` seta para `null` depois da primeira execução:

```
<script>

    document.onclick = function(e) 
    {
        myFunction();   
    }

    function myFunction() 
    {
        window.open("http://google.com.br", "_blank",
    "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=1, left=1, width=1, height=1");

       document.onclick = null; // anulando na próxima execução.
    }

</script>
```

***Referencia:*** [GlobalEventHandlers.onclick](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onclick)

Answer (score 1):

Isso é simples declare uma variável no início tipo `var click = false` e quando a pessoa clicar você coloca essa variável para `true` e coloque um `if statement` para verificar se a variável é falsa, se ela for, abre a janela. E quando recarregar a página a variável vai voltar para falsa.